# Is there a way to take a value from associate array knowing the value without iterating through all the array?

Tags: php, associative-array

I want to take a value from the array for example Win where UName = demo123, which in this case is **66**

I have array with around 2k entities, those are only the first 2 of them.

```
[0] => Array

    (
        [Win] => 23
        [BookID] => 1863
        [Name] => Second Book Name
        [UName] => example
        [UserID] => 4916
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Win] => 66
        [BookID] => 467
        [Name] => BookName
        [UName] => demo123
        [UserID] => 269
    )
```

I know I can take the value with a loop like this

```
foreach ($d['author'] as $author) {
     if ($author['UName'] == 'demo123') {
         $win += $author['Win'];
     }
}
```

But is there a simple way with a function to do this?

Comment: This is the simplest way. All other ways will be __less__ readable and understandable.

Comment: You could make it faster, but your way is the easiest to understand as u_mulder pointed out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. Even if there was, the function would probably execute a loop as well because that's the only way to find a value in an array like this.

Comment: If the array is sorted by name or indexed in some way you could do this faster

Comment: True, but to sort the array, you will also have to iterate it several times.

Comment: Depends on how the array is created, if it's coming out of a relational database you're probably fine